# Pepper Robot Web Debugging

Tags: web, tablet, pepper

We're trying to show a web page on pepper's tablet, but something goes wrong. How can we get the browser's error messages to debug the web page?

We know js 1.5 is implemented, so we installed all kind of polyfills for Promises, forEach, etc. But no luck. How can we get meaningful debugging info?

Answer (score 0):

I create a git for showing a web page and send event with the module ALMemory ( [see it for an example](http://protolab.aldebaran.com:9000/protolab/tutorials/tree/master/ConnectionHtmlChoregraphe)). For debugging, it is more complicated but you can also try [this](https://github.com/pepperhacking/robot-jumpstarter). You can create a template for showing web page and connect directly it to your robot. For example, you install it on your pc and create a web-page template with `python jumpstart.py service-tabletpage my-package-name MyServiceName`. A package will be create in a file output. Open this app on choregraphe and install it on the robot. You can after that launch on your computer the web page (double click on index.html, name by default) and just adding at the end of the url `?robot=ip_of_the_robot`. You can now debug your code.